# What are advantageous features are in SCSS/Less/Sass vs <?php header("Content-type: text/css");

Tags: php, css, sass, less

I'm a long-time PHP developer, and although I've done lots of clever things with CSS, I've never really gotten deep into SCSS/Less/Sass.

Working in LAMP stack, I've never seen anything from SCSS/Less/Sass that I couldn't do better by just having my "css file" be a .php file with

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
/* Variables to be used in the following CSS heredoc */
echo <<< CSS
/* Lots of CSS code here that grabs calculated variables when I need them */
CSS;
?>
```

In a LAMP stack, this strikes me as significantly more versatile and straightforward than installing additional SCSS/Less/Sass compilers and following their syntax, and it allows the full language to come into play.

Yet, I see SCSS/Less/Sass used all the time in LAMP stacks, and the header technique I almost never see used except by myself and a rare few others. I've tried both SCSS/Less/Sass a few times, and just got annoyed by the limitations. What am I missing?

What are the features provided by SCSS/Less/Sass that are missing by just creating a PHP filed with a css header declaration?

(The only one I've found on my own is that old versions of IE will insist on treating the .php extension as -not- a css file, but that's easily addressed by a one-or-two line .htaccess redirect,

but that minor one-time inconvenience doesn't seem to balance out the loss of functionality?).

Comment: Use whatever your scenario requires. If neither are required for any reason over the other, then just pick one. This is too broad and opinionated for this site. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Often people publish "built" versions of the front end assets where files are combined, minified etc. When running these tools on the frontend before releasing a new version it's very conventient to be able to expand other SCSS projects (like bootstrap) by simply changing some variables etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sass can handle a lot more than mere variables. If you think that's the only/main benefit of Sass,

you [really want to dig into the docs a bit more](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html).

First off, one of the most useful features is allowing nesting that native CSS doesn't permit. This lets you group your rules in a logical manner, so this:

```
#main {
    // some rules
}

#main .p {
    // some more rules
}
```

becomes the cleaner (and more importantly, *clearer* from a logical/readability standpoint):

```
#main {
    // some rules

    p {
        // some rules just for paragraphs
    }
}
```

It's also handy for logically grouping pseudo classes with their elements:

```
a {
    // some rules

    &:hover {
        // some rules just for the hover
    }
}
```

The same approach as above can be used with media queries, too. Very handy:

```
#foo {
    // some rules

    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        // some media queried rules
    }
}
```

Or for math PHP can't natively handle (an obviously contrived example follows, but this sort of thing *can* be quite useful):

```
width: 1px + 1px + 1px;
```

Color math:

```
>> #777 + #777
#eeeeee
```

There are a wide variety of [built-in functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) you'd have to duplicate in PHP. The color ones can be quite useful, in my experience.

A final note: Most folks I've seen going the PHP-as-CSS route don't do any sort of caching on it, requiring PHP to generate the CSS every time. Sass compiles down to *static* files, which is easier on your server.

Comment: Oh... don't forget things like [control expressions like `@for`, `@each`, `@if`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#control_directives__expressions), [mix-ins](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) for your own custom functions, `@extends` to do an `include()` style inclusion of another rule, and more. The "loss of functionality" you describe may just be a lack of understanding of how powerful Sass etc. actually are.

Comment: Thanks for the control expressions info. As for the 'loss of functionality' I refer to, I actually mean the benefits of having a fully robust language behind it (like building with while loops, database queries to populate the css, fetching time/date to change functionality, assinging backgrounds based on user variables, doing stuff based on the session such as changing header color if they're logged in vs not logged in rather than switching classes, scientific calculations for 3d transforms, etc.) But you're right, I don't understand how powerful Sass is, hence the question.

Comment: @liljoshu So, all of that is possible, but the logic shouldn't really be in the CSS in the same way you're thinking. Some examples... changing functionality by time/date you'd potentially do by putting `<body class="morning">` or `<div class="new">` or whatnot and some CSS rules that apply to `.morning` or `.new`. Use your PHP to spit out *class names* in the HTML, not rules in the CSS.

Comment: Header color if logged in versus not works the same way. You'd do something like `<body class="logged-in">` and then do `body.logged-in #header { color: red; }`.

Comment: For genuinely unique stuff - like a user-configured background image - you can use `<body style="background-image: <?php echo $foo; ?>">` or output a `<style>` tag in the head.

Comment: Good suggestions on most of those. Only exception I see is for the background image, meaning including the link every time you use it, while if client-side caching is on, makes it so it only needs to be passed once. Setting them in-line gets cumbersome if it's a whole user-defined theme.

Comment: Yes, if you're letting users set entire custom themes, you'll probably need to take the database-driven PHP approach there. You can still make the main site CSS with Sass, and include the user's CSS afterwards as a separate (PHP-driven) CSS file. Benefits of both, that way.

Comment: Fair enough. I've always tried to aim for only one file call for styles to reduce http calls, but you're right, that case does seem like it'd do quite well with two separate calls to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: "There are a wide variety of built-in functions you'd have to duplicate in PHP." In fact there are a lot of PHP Function you'll have to duplicate in SASS....